# Connecting 2 Raspberry Pi together

Tags: pi-3, arduino

Is it possible to connect 2 Raspberry Pi 3's together using cable?
(I read somewhere and show some videos that an Arduino can be connected to a Pi using a serial cable.)

One of the Raspberry Pi's will be used as a gateway and a CoAP server that communicates with sensor nodes that is on the other Pi. The sensor will be a DHT22 sensor for temperature.

The Arduino part of the question is because I saw this. Just asking if it can happen pi to pi.

[image]

Comment: If you connect the UART/Serial Header on both PI's together, flipping rx/tx wire. You will have bi-directional communication over serial terminal `/dev/ttyASM0`. However since you have the full linux networking stack, using IP even if its just a two node network is still a very viable option

Comment: Of course you can. Heck, you can even do it *wirelessly* (I mean WiFi). It's just that there's so many ways to do it (GPIO/Serial/I2C/SPI/USB modules/Ethernet/whatever). Try some!

Answer (score 4):

There are a variety of options for connecting two Raspberry Pis together.

The easiest, if both Raspberry Pis are already on the same wireless network, is not to bother with a cable and just communicate over the existing network.

A second option is to create a dedicated network between the two devices by connecting them directly with an Ethernet cable.  Configure `eth0` statically on each system so that each has a unique ip, and you're all set.

There are other options available (e.g., wiring their serial ports together), but unless you have a very specific use case I suspect that one of the above network solutions will be the easiest to implement and use.